# Where do I access the Online Contracts Introduction?

Tags: watch-dogs

In the Online Contracts App accessed from the in-game smart phone, there are two modes ("Online Tailing" and "Online Hacking"). I assume these are the modes where other players can jump into my live game, or I can jump into theirs.

These modes both say "Complete Online Contracts Introduction to unlock". Where is this introduction?

Note I have just recently unlocked the second area (The Loop), and am at 3/9 in Act 1, for some idea of my progression through the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer showed up just after I posted this question.

As I reached the location for the next mission ("Backseat Driver") and attempted to start the mission, I was informed that another fixer was attempting to hack me.

The game then required me to navigate to an area indicated on the map by a purple circle. When I reached that location (for me, this was the parking garage where I'd just completed a side-mission) I had to scan people until I found the rival fixer (it appears that this is always a bot called 2XTheTap) and chase him down and shoot him.

After this, I was able to access both the Online Hacking and Online Tailing modes.

[Some research](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/How-Unlock-Watch-Dogs-Multiplayer-64337.html) shows this is the [standard way](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-05-27-watch-dogs-walkthrough-and-game-guide) to unlock this feature.